# How to use import and require in the same file - Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, url

I'm trying to use normalize-url package but it must be imported instead of required, as it is not supported in ES module. I tried to get around this issue by adding two lines of code I found online that supposedly would solve the problem but it ain't working for me. Here is the link for the solution https://www.kindacode.com/article/node-js-how-to-use-import-and-require-in-the-same-file/

```
import { createRequire } from "module";const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
import normalizeUrl from 'normalize-url';
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const config = require('config');
const axios = require('axios');
```

I also included `"type": "module",` in my package.json.
The error msg:
`
[0] const express = require('express');

[0] ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
[0] This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension`

Comment: Why don't you use import for all of them, instead of trying to mix import and require?

Answer (score 0):

You should just use import from all of them.