# User require and Import within same file react js chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-extension, import, require

I'm developing a google chrome extension with reactjs and I need to use `translate` module or package within my chrome extension but I'm failing to use it and I'm facing error to switch require command to import to move forward.

I also tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73549968/how-to-use-import-and-require-in-the-same-file-node-js) but It doesn't work for me. Please see if anyone can help me to get rid of it. Thanks

**package.json:**

```json
{
  "name": "medium-extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "free-translate": "^0.6.1",
    "google-translate-api": "^2.3.0",
    "openai": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "translate": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@types/chrome": "0.0.177",
    "@types/google-translate-api": "^2.3.2",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^10.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  }
}
```

**background.ts:**

```
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

const translate = require('free-translate');

(async () => {
     const translatedText = await translate('This is cool!', { to: 'ja' });
  
     console.log(translatedText); // これはカッコいい！
})();
```

[image]

[image]

[How to use import and require in the same file - Node JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73549968/how-to-use-import-and-require-in-the-same-file-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

as you found, you can't mix imports and requires. I am fairly confident that you are just seeing an error with your ide (it doent understand that you are replacing `require`, and thinks you are rrying to use the built in one). I believe the code would run fine if you tried it.

that being said - rather than hack in `require`, you can dynamically import the module

replace this code

```js
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

const translate = require('free-translate');
```

with this

```js
const { translate } = await import('free-translate')
```

Comment: Thanks for checking but it's not working for me. I'm using it in the background.ts and my ide showed like its not allowed to import like that

Comment: did you run the code? As I mentioned,  I am fairly confident that you are just seeing an error with your ide. unless you are using a old version of node

Comment: Here is the detail of the environments.
Node version: v18.13.0
NPM: 8.19.3

Comment: Yes, I ran the code and it's not working.

Comment: not working how? what specific error? the code is correct. I can run it without a problem on node v18.13.0